# iOS Push Notification - sfmc_handle() not called when app was closed

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, ios, notification, mobilepush-ios

If the app is already open or in the background, and a push notification is sent to the device then `sfmc_handle(_ url: URL, type: String)` is fired properly. Everything works as expected as the link attached to the push notification is handled.

But if the app is closed, and a push notification is tapped to open the app then `sfmc_handle(_ url: URL, type: String)` ***never triggers***.

In our app, `MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_configure(with: builder)` is called at the beginning of the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()`, and the delegate is set immediately once the configuration is successful:

`MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_setURLHandlingDelegate(self)`

Based on the SDK documentation for iOS, all of this is setup properly. It seems that perhaps when the app is launched from a "cold start" the delegate hasn't been fully configured by the time the url is passed to the app from the push notification.

But if this is the case, then what is missing in the configuration setup? Or is this a bug in the iOS SDK?

Does it matter if we have this in the builder `sfmc_setDelayRegistration(untilContactKeyIsSet: true)`?

Answer (score 2):

As you know, the SDK relies on the implementer to pass the notification to it in order to handle urls, report correct analytics etc. There are 2 things to verify:

1. The SDK is initialized when passed the notification.
2. The notification is intercepting the notification from Apple's delegate methods and passing it to the SDK correctly.

For your situation I believe you are setting the delegate and initializing the SDK in the correct places. The issue is not correctly intercepting the notification when coming from a closed app state. Apple has indicated that intercepting remote notifications from a closed app state can be done via the `launchOptions` in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` or in iOS 13 the `connectionOptions` in `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)`. I have provided 2 examples below verifying the SDK is configured and then intercepting the remote notification:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

       let result = configureMarketingCloudSDK() // Example method to configure the SDK

       if let launchOptions = launchOptions,
           let userInfo = launchOptions[.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable: Any], result {
               MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_setNotificationUserInfo(userInfo)
        }
 
       return result
}
```

For iOS 13 SceneDelegate

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

   let result = configureMarketingCloudSDK() // Example method to configure the SDK
   
   if let response = connectionOptions.notificationResponse, result {
        MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_setNotificationUserInfo(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
   }

   guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
}
```

In here feel free to extract out the url from the notification payload (userInfo) and pass it to `sfmc_handleUrl`

Finally, from our sdk docs: "The below method will be invoked even if the application was launched or resumed because of the remote notification. The respective delegate methods will be invoked first. Note that this behavior is in contrast to `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`, which is not called in those cases, and which will not be invoked if this method is implemented."

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_setNotificationUserInfo(userInfo)
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
```

Comment: So the appDelegate launchOptions did not work. I assume it's because we're targeting iOS 14.0 and above? We implemented the SceneDelegate with connectionOptions and that solved it. Now we're getting push notifications to be handled when the app is closed so we can then parse the incoming Url for deep linking. Thanks Skyler!